# How to foreach data in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know good enough of ASP.NET and C#, but I know Laravel (php). Problem is how to `foreach` data in a view in SQL Server data. I already checked database connection that was good I think. In Laravel, I just take Model's to collection and return it and `foreach` it. In ASP.NET, I'm stuck.

Controller index method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        var model = service.Get

        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomDatabase");

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Programy",connection);
        var count = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

        ViewData["TotalData"] = count;
        connection.Close();

        return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ClaimBased.Models.Program>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<h3>Total data: @ViewData["TotalData"]</h3>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
 </table>
```

Model:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClaimBased.Models
{
    public class Program
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what part did you retrieve the `IEnumerable<ClaimBased.Models.Program>` from your database? You need to retrieve it first and pass it to `return View()`.

Comment: yeah by variable i saw that on example. but how bro?

Comment: Simply write return View(model);

Comment: Like this? `return View(Program)` ? I tried it already.